# How to convert to String?

Tags: octave

Below commands :

```
theta = zeros(2, 1);        
printf(theta)
```

Give error : `error: printf: format TEMPLATE must be a string`

Is there function to convert the `theta` to a String or to print the `theta` value ?

Reading the octave doc : http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/octave3/octave_140.html this does seem possible ?

Comment: print(theta) maybe or give format string(as in any printf function in any language/environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to sprint to the `stdout` stream then you can use `printf` *without* converting to a string as it will do this for you but it works like any string formatting function in any language where the first argument is a string followed by variables you want to format and insert into that string. for your simple case:

```
printf('%f', theta)
```

If you are just trying to print to the console however, I would suggest rather using `sprintf` or `display`. Matlab doesn't have a `printf` command and I would always advocate keeping your Octave code directly portable to Matlab when possible.

Answer (score 1):

`matstr` function

For my case : `printf(mat2str(theta , 2))`

src : https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using `printf` in the first place and is a very round about way to go. `printf` will convert and format your matrix for you if you use it properly. See my answer for an example (also note that there are examples in the doc page you linked to in your question). I see you're coming from a Java background, `printf` is just like the Java equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Use `num2str()`

eg

```
str_theta = num2str(theta)
```

[Octave documentaion on converting numbers to strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings.html#Converting-Numerical-Data-to-Strings)